# Azure Bot Framework Direct Line - How to change Language?

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot, direct-line-botframework

I'm following the following sample https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Samples/blob/master/docs-samples/web-chat-speech/index.html

If I use option 2 "Native browser speech" the input is still in English while the output is in german.

```
  BotChat.App({
    bot: bot,
    locale: 'de-DE',
    resize: 'detect',
    // sendTyping: true,    // defaults to false. set to true to send 'typing' activities to bot (and other users) when user is typing
    speechOptions: speechOptions,
    user: user,

    directLine: {
        domain: params['domain'],
        secret: params['s'],
        token: params['t'],
        webSocket: params['webSocket'] && params['webSocket'] === 'true' // defaults to true
    }
```

I just changed the

```
locale = 'de-DE'
```

how to get the microphone input in german as well?

Or how to get it to work with option 3?

Thanks.

Comment: To understand, are you wanting user microphone input in English to translate to German in Web Chat, or something else to happen?

Comment: Also, if this is a new implementation of Web Chat you are building, I would highly recommend the v4 ("Web Chat") option instead of v3 ("BotChat"). BotChat is no longer supported and has been deprecated. Web Chat, however, has been redesigned with a much higher degree of customization and is fully compatible with the v3 or v4 version of BotBuilder.